# How to create an active tilde in LaTeX 3

Tags: expl3, expansion, hhline

I have some  LaTeX3 code that generates matrices and uses the [hhline](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package internally. In LaTeX3 the `~` character is a special character, used for inserting spaces in strings, and using `\c_tilde_str` results in [hhline](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) ignoring the character and giving the warning:

```
Package hhline Warning: macro:->~ ignored in \hhline argument
```

I have tried various tricks such as defining

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__active_tilde { \~ }
\group_begin:
\char_set_active_eq:nN  {`~} \__active_tilde
\group_end:
```

and then using `\__active_tilde` but this does not work either.

Here is a minimal working example that exhibits my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\mat{
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
  \begin{array}{cc} \hhline{~-} 1&2 \end{array}
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
  \begin{array}{cc} \hhline{\c_tilde_str-} 1&2 \end{array}
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mat$

\end{document}
```

This produces the output

[image]

with the overline over the `1`'s instead of the `2`'s. The log file contains the lines:

```
Package hhline Warning: macro:->~ ignored in \hhline argument
(hhline)                 on input line 24.
```

This shows that the first `~` is being ignored, as it should be since `~` is a space in `expl` code, and that the `\c_tilde_str` is not being recognised as a `~` by `hhline`.

[I know that the `tabularray` package gives other ways of doing this but it does not work in my real use-case because it does not support expansion in its key-value syntax -- and for the number of tables that I need to produce there may be other performance issues...]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\let\foo~
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\mat{
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
  \begin{array}{cc} \hhline{\foo-} 1&2 \end{array}
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
  \begin{array}{cc} \hhline{\foo-} 1&2 \end{array}
\typeout{----------------------------------------}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mat$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that I tried this...

Comment: OK, as I am generating the `\hhline` parameter dynamically this needs `\exp_args:Ne \hhline{\exp_not:N \foo\l_tmpa_tl}`. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.